# How do you update a node using Services in Drupal?

Tags: rest, drupal, service, drupal-7

hi what its the endpoint's url to update a node and what it's de json request to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the services module for a standardized approach to web services https://www.drupal.org/project/services

Comment: You didn't answer the question at all. You just linked to the drupal project.

Comment: ok to be more specific there is no out of the box way to update a node Drupal node via web services. You need to create your own module or use the fantastic services module I pointed you too above. Building modules is beyond the scope of my answer but I think if you try out the services module and read the documentation you will understand how to do exactly what you want.